# Cannot set DataGrid row header value

Tags: c#, forms, datagrid

I'm having difficulty setting the header value for DataGrid rows. 
**My DataGrid is bounded to DataTable** but the following code won't display the row's header for the first row. Any ideas?

**Note**: RowHeadersVisible = True

(Assume that my DataTable has at least 1 col and 1 row before reaching this code)

```
    public new void ShowDialog()
    {
        dataGridView_replaceTable.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridView_replaceTable.Rows.Clear();

        dataGridView_replaceTable.DataSource = getDataTable(); <-- returns DataTable

        dataGridView_replaceTable.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "ROW HEADER 1";
        // I expect to see the this string in the first row header - but it remians empty!
    }
```

The code for adding rows and columns to the DataTable:

we have:

> replaceTableValues DataTable

as class property.

```
    public void addCol()
    {
        DataColumn column;

        column = new DataColumn(string colName);
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = colName;
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        replaceTableValues.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    public void addRow()
    {
        DataRow row;

        row = replaceTableValues.NewRow();

        string[] arr = new string[numOfCols+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = ""; // fill row data as empty string
        }

        try
        {
            replaceTableValues.Rows.Add(arr);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            updateReplaceVarErrorMsg(TABLE_EXCEPTION);
        }

    }
```

What i'm trying to achieve: (red text)
[Image](http://i40.tinypic.com/2wq8hvp.png)

Thanks.

Comment: try `dataGridView_replaceTable.Columns[0].Name = "ROW HEADER 1";`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HeaderText` property of `Columns` collection instead:

```
dataGridView_replaceTable.Columns[0].HeaderText="ROW HEADER 1";
```

You could also do this when you add your columns by using `Caption` property:

```
public void addCol()
{
    DataColumn column;

    column = new DataColumn(string colName);
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    column.ColumnName = colName;
    column.Caption = "My header" // ASSIGN HEADERS HERE
    column.ReadOnly = false;
    replaceTableValues.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that's what I want to achieve. I'm adding an image illustrating it.. (I also tried your code and nothing changed)

Comment: @etaiso I'm waiting for the image :)

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know what you wanna do couldn't be done using ordinary `GridView` properties. By the way, this is not called _Header_ I myself call these _Sider_ :). I use a custom user control for grid instead. I added this "Sider" to it and it also has some better styles, but some limitations too. You could also do this by "Hacking" the GridView using some low level messages.

Comment: sorry I added it to the main thread but forgot to put it here a well.. here you go: http://i40.tinypic.com/2wq8hvp.png

Comment: Is there other object that behave like a table/matrix with more options like this? I would also like the option to copy a specific column by selecting it and pressing the regular CTRL+C shortcut. As now it won't copy any data unless you double click on a specific cell and then the text become editable..

Comment: @etaiso I can share my user control, it has been created by someone else and I improved some features, we can add CTRL-C option too. Please get in touch with me ehsabd{at}gmail.com

Comment: I've found that the original author of that custom grid improved its features maybe this suffice for you [Super Fast Grid 3.0](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9036&lngWId=10)

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Something special";
```

A basic way to add a column is:

```
int columnIndex = grid.Columns.Add("columnName", "Header Text");
```

Comment: You want header of existing column or you want to set header for column?

Comment: I want header/caption for row.. As in the image attached above.